# How can I get an svg symbol to reference another symbol in an external file?

Tags: svg, symbols, xlink

I'm trying to reference a symbol inside a symbol in an external file, but can't get it to work in Chrome or Firefox.

I can reference a symbol in another symbol if they are defined at the top of the html file no problem with this:

```
<!-- in the html file -->
<svg width="0" height="0">

  <symbol id="local-circle" viewBox="0 0 100 100" overflow="visible">
    <circle
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="50"
      fill="red"
    />
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="local-sym" viewBox="0 0 100 100" overflow="visible">
    <rect
      x="0"
      y="0"
      width="100"
      height="100"
      fill="blue"
    />
    <use
      xlink:href="#local-circle"
      x="0"
      y="0"
      width="100"
      height="100"
    />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

But when I try to put this code in an external file, the symbol inside a symbol doesn't show up.

```
<!-- in an external file called test.svg -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <!-- This shows up fine in the html file -->
  <symbol id="ext-circle" viewBox="0 0 100 100" overflow="visible">
    <circle
      cx="50"
      cy="50"
      r="50"
      fill="red"
    />
  </symbol>

  <!-- But here, the rect shows up, but not the referenced circle -->
  <symbol id="ext-sym" viewBox="0 0 100 100" overflow="visible">
    <rect
      x="0"
      y="0"
      width="100"
      height="100"
      fill="blue"
    />
    <use
      xlink:href="#ext-circle"
      x="0"
      y="0"
      width="100"
      height="100"
    />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

I even tried a combination where the in-file symbol references the external symbol, but with no luck:

```
<!-- in the html file -->
<svg width="0" height="0">

  <symbol id="combo-sym" viewBox="0 0 100 100" overflow="visible">
    <rect
      x="0"
      y="0"
      width="100"
      height="100"
      fill="blue"
    />
    <use
      xlink:href="test.svg#ext-circle"
      x="0"
      y="0"
      width="100"
      height="100"
    />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Any idea how I can make this work? I will have many symbols and I don't want to have to define them all in the html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external svg is invalid as it's missing an xlink namespace definition i.e. xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink". Once I fixed that the circle shows up fine in Firefox.

```
<svg>
    <use
      xlink:href="test.svg#ext-sym"
      x="0"
      y="0"
      width="100"
      height="100"
    />
</svg>
```